# CSP issues with javascript and css - password visibility toggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, content-security-policy

I am currently working on some frontend development on a server. However when I try to add inline css and javascript for my password visibility toggle I keep getting the same CSP errors in google chrome.

`Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' ssl.google-analytics.com`

The code I have tried :

```
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="block full-width mb2 field-light input-shadow">
    <span toggle="#password" class="hidden toggle-password icon-eye" id="togglePassword"></span>

<style $nonceAttr>
    .toggle-password {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: -47px;
        right: 3.2rem;
        cursor:pointer;
        background-position: center;
    }
    .icon-eye {
        background-image: url(/images/eye-icon.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .icon-eye-slash {
        background-image: url(/images/eye-slash-icon.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    form input::-ms-reveal, form input::-ms-clear {
        display: none;
    }
    input[type=password].password-form-field, input[type=text].password-form-field {
        padding-right: 46px !important;
    }
</style>

<script type="application/javascript" $nonceAttr>
        $("form input[type='password']").on("input", function(){
                    if($(this).val()) {
                            $(this).next(".toggle-password").removeClass("hidden");
                        } else {
                            $(this).next(".toggle-password").addClass("hidden");
                        }
                });
        $(".toggle-password").click(function() {
                    $(this).toggleClass("icon-eye icon-eye-slash");
                    var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
                    if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
                            input.attr("type", "text");
                        } else {
                            input.attr("type", "password");
                        }
                });

</script>
```

It works great on both internet explorer and microsoft edge, but refuses to work on google chrome. I would need help figuring out this problem. Is it that CSP has no support for $(".toggle-password").click? I also tried move the js and css into seperate external files but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding 'unsafe-inline' to your CSP list.

E.g.,

script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ssl.google-analytics.com

Comment: I tried this solution, interestingly I tested another javascript to handle something else and that seems to work fine but my toggle pass code is still denied. I guess the problem has to do with CSP not allowing certain javascript code?

Comment: I will accept this answer as a resolution, it seems like it indeed started to work after adding ’unsafe-inline’. Apparently it took several minutes before it actually worked after initially adding ’unsafe-inline’, hence the previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSP: `"script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' ssl.google-analytics.com` does not contain a `'nonce-RandomValue'` whish should correspond to `$nonceAttr` (nonce='RandomValue') used in `<script>`/`<style>`

Comment: The nonce seems to be fine since I manage to get some other javascript code running its just my toggle pass code that doesn't run so I assume CSP doesnt allow some javascript/jquery code?

Comment: Also, my CSP looks like <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' $nonceAttr;">

Comment: I just do not observe any `'nonce-hgf56efe'` in the violation report. It should looks like: `directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-hgf56efe' 'unsafe-eval' ssl.google-analytics.com`. Which bersion of jQuery do uou use? jQuery fully supports `'nonce-value'` and redistrubutes it into dynamically created childs scripts since [v3.5](https://csplite.com/csp/test379/#jQuery_3.x).